# Locational triangulation

Tags: python, math, 2d, triangulation

I have data about 10 points in a 2D map, I know the location of points 1,2 and 3. I also know the distance between point 1,2 and 3 to all other points.

I know that cell phone uses distance from gsm towers to locate their location. I wish to use similar approach to locate points 3-10. How can I implement such a solution with python? Which libraries can I use?

Thank you for all help

Comment: You are describing *trilateration* since you use distances and not angles.

Comment: If you know :

 - the positions of 3 points (x1,y1),(x2,y2) and (x3,y3)
 - the distance of a 4th point (x4,y4) to the previous points d1,d2,d3

Then the following property is true for every i in {1,2,3} : (xi-x4)^2 + (yi-y4)^2 = di^2.

That should be enough for you to do the maths to determine x4 and y4.

Comment: MAV thank alot! that was the starting point I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, solve the math. Make a drawing. You will find that you can use two points and their distance to reduce the possible points to just two, the third one will only be needed to disambiguate between the two. Putting the whole into Python should be easy then.

Note that I'm not going to spell this out completely for you, because it is customary to not spoil other programmers the experience of doing their own homework, doing research etc. If you have something that you have a problem with, then ask specific questions and demonstrate some effort on your side first.